# Starting and stopping a remote service using WMI and Start-Job

Tags: powershell, wmi

Why does this work:

```
$bits = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -ComputerName computer -Credential $creds | 
? name -Like "bits*"

$bits.StopService()
```

but with this

```
$bits = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -ComputerName computer -Credential $creds | 
? name -Like "bits*"

$stopbits = Start-Job {$bits.StopService()}
```

I get an error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"

I'm trying to write a script that will stop a set of services in a set order.  I only have WMI available to me.  By using Start-Job I want to then use

```
$stopbits = Start-Job {$bits.StopService()}
Wait-Job -Id $stopbits.id
```

before going to the next service.  I am a powershell beginner so I could be going about this all wrong.  I would appreciate any help on getting this to work.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke WMI Method called StopService to execute the job.
Something like this.

```
$stopbits = Start-Job {
  $bits.InvokeMethod("StopService",$null)
}
```

On second thoughts, the above code won't work too as $bits object is not defined in the local scope.
So you need to do this.

```
$global:creds = Get-credential
$stopbits = Start-Job {
  $bits = Get-WmiObject `
    -Class win32_service `
    -ComputerName $computer `
    -Credential $global:creds | 
      where name -Like "bits*"
  $bits.StopService()
}
```

Comment: So, If I'm understanding this correctly, the $bits variable is null because it isn't defined within the start-job scriptblock?

Comment: Yes. $bits is not defined in the local scope.

Answer (score 0):

The $bits variable isn't defined in the scope of the background job.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell 7.x, WMI isn't supported any more. In that case you'd need to use CIM instead.
Besides, using CIM has a bunch of advantages (and some disadvantages).

```
$Creds = Get-Credential

$Bits = Get-CimInstance `
  -Class Win32_Service `
  -ComputerName 'computer' `
  -Credential $Creds `
  -Filter 'Name LIKE "bits%"' 

Start-Job {
  $Using:Bits | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName StopService
} | Receive-Job -Wait
```

Ref 1: [MS DevBlogs - Should I use CIM or WMI with Windows PowerShell?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/should-i-use-cim-or-wmi-with-windows-powershell/)
Ref 2: [MS Learn - Getting WMI objects with Get-CimInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/getting-wmi-objects--get-ciminstance-?view=powershell-5.1)